# $\mathbb{E}[M_{\tau+\theta}M_{\tau}]=\mathbb{E}[M_{\tau}^2]$

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

> Let $\{M_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ be a martingale with mean zero and filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t \geq 0}$.
>
> I want to show that if $\tau$ and $\theta$ are stopping times bounded by $T < \infty$ then
>
> $$\mathbb{E}[M_{\tau+\theta}M_{\tau}]=\mathbb{E}[M_{\tau}^2].$$

If I had $\mathbb{E}[M_{t+s}M_{t}]$ with $s,t \in \mathbb{R^+}$, I would know how to solve it:

$$\mathbb{E}[M_{t+s}M_{t}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[M_{t+s}M_{t} | \mathcal{F}_t]]=\mathbb{E}[M_{t}\mathbb{E}[M_{t+s}|\mathcal{F}_t]]=\mathbb{E}[M_{t}^2].$$

But I have stopping times instead of deterministic times.

I think I have to use the optional stopping theorem but I'm not sure how. I might be missing some hypothesis on the martingale (so that we can apply the optional stopping theorem) so , is there any assumption I have to make about $\{M_t\}_{t \geq 0}$? (for example convergence in $L^1$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. To change your argument to use stopping times you just need to change the $\sigma$-algebra against which you condition. We can do that via the following proposition.

**Proposition** Let $\{X_t\}$ be a right-continuous martingale for which $X_\infty = \lim_{t \to \infty} X_t$ exists almost surely. If $S$ and $T$ are two stopping times with $S \leq T$, then $X_T$ is integrable and $\mathbb{E}(X_T | \mathcal{F}_S) = X_S$ almost surely.

This proposition can be proven (with a bit of work, see Theorem 77.5 in Diffusions, Markov Processes, and Martingales by Rogers and Williams) from the optional stopping theorem. Now, your result follows by the following computation:

$$\mathbb{E}(M_{\tau + \theta} M_\tau) = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(M_{\tau + \theta} M_\tau \, | \, \mathcal{F}_\tau)] = \mathbb{E}[M_\tau \mathbb{E}(M_{\tau + \theta}  \, | \, \mathcal{F}_\tau)] = \mathbb{E}(M_{\tau}^2)$$

Where we have used the fact that $M_\tau$ is $\mathcal{F}_\tau$-measurable in the second equality and the proposition in the third equality. To see that $M_\tau$ is $\mathcal{F}_\tau$-measurable, fix $t \geq 0$, let $r(\omega) = (\tau (\omega ), \omega)$, and let $M_{(t)}^*$ be the restriction of $M$ to $[0,t] \times \tau^{-1}([0, t])$. Let $\mathcal{F}_t^*$ be $\mathcal{F}_t$ relativised to $\tau^{-1}([0,t])$. We then note that for an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we have: $$\{ M_\tau (\omega) \in U \} \cap \{ \tau \leq t \} = \left(M_{(t)}^* \circ r \right)^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{F}_t^* \subset \mathcal{F}_t$$
Since this holds for all $t \geq 0$, we conclude $M_\tau$ is $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ measurable.

Comment: Why is $X_{\tau}$ $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$-measurable?

Comment: @Babado It can be shown with a bit of symbol pushing. See my edit.

Comment: I don't get what $\mathcal{F}_t^*$is and why $\left(M_{(t)}^* \circ r \right)^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{F}_t^*$. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Babado $\mathcal{F}_t^* = \{ \tau^{-1}([0,t]) \cap E\, : \, E \in \mathcal{F}_t \}$. Can you see then that $r : \tau^{-1}([0,t]) \to [0,t] \times \tau^{-1}([0,t])$ is measurable and $M_{(t)}^* : [0,t] \times \tau^{-1}([0,t]) \to \mathbb{R}$ is also measurable?

Comment: Is that it?
\
$M_{(t)}^*$ is $\mathcal{F}_t^*$- measurable because given an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $(M_{(t)}^*)^{-1}(U) = \Omega_1 \cap \tau^{-1}([0,t]) \in \mathcal{F}_t^*$ (where $\Omega_1 = M_t^{-1}(U) \in \mathcal{F}_t $)

\
$r_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t^*$- measurable because given $A \in \mathcal{F}_t$ , $r^{-1}([0,t] \times [A \cap \tau^{-1}([0,t])])= A \cap \tau^{-1}([0,t]) \in \mathcal{F}_t^*$ \
The composition of measurable functions is then a measurable function.

Comment: @Babado Looks right to me!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!